# extracting digits from image opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to extract numbers / digits from below image:

[image from which to extract digits](https://pasteboard.co/HzKxx0j.png)

1st I tried it with OCR, but the output is not relevant, so I planned to use `opencv` with `python`

I have written the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


#cv2.IMREAD_COLOR = 1 , Loads a color image. Any transparency of image will be neglected. It is the default flag.
#cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE = 0 , Loads image in grayscale mode
#cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED = -1 , Loads image as such including alpha channel
image = cv2.imread( './in.png' , 1 )


gray = cv2.cvtColor( image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY )

ret1, thresh1 = cv2.threshold( gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY )

image[ thresh1 == 0 ] = 255

kernal = cv2.getStructuringElement( cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, ( 5,5 ) )
erosion = cv2.erode( image, kernal, iterations = 1 )

cv2.imwrite( 'res.png', erosion )
```

and the output I got is:

[output result image](https://pasteboard.co/HzKzI5Q.png)

at this point I am at least standing somewhere to accomplish my task, but I am not able to decide further step to extract things, I googled and found something `contours` from `opencv` so I tried using this code:

```
from imutils.perspective import four_point_transform
from imutils import contours
import imutils
import cv2

#cv2.IMREAD_COLOR = 1 , Loads a color image. Any transparency of image will be neglected. It is the default flag.
#cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE = 0 , Loads image in grayscale mode
#cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED = -1 , Loads image as such including alpha channel
image = cv2.imread( './input.png' , 1 )

image = imutils.resize(image, height=500)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
edged = cv2.Canny(blurred, 50, 200, 255)

cv2.imwrite( 'res.png', edged )
```

and I got the output image as:
[image]

again as per the `contours` logic I am not able to point out how I can find the placement of required digits inside the image.

I am really confused, How can I extract digits from the image.

I m looking for some hints or guide and even codes to accomplish my task

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you looking to extract the seven segment digits or only handwritten? In any case, it will be good to select a region of interest in the image which you want to concentrate on. Opencv has a function for this, cv2.selectROI which will be helpful.

Comment: The author on this website has done some related work using opencv and python for 7segment digit recognition. You can take a look. Hope it helps. https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/13/recognizing-digits-with-opencv-and-python/

Comment: A first step that may consist to process a gray image from CIE-Lab space:
i.e.

    Lab = cv2.cvtColor(I,cv2.COLOR_BGR2Lab)
    L,a,b = cv2.split(Lab)
    Ig = cv2.addWeighted(a,0.5,b,0.5,0,dtype=cv2.CV_32F)
    Ig = cv2.divide(Ig,L,dtype=cv2.CV_32F)
    Ig = cv2.normalize(Ig,None,0.,255.,cv2.NORM_MINMAX,cv2.CV_8U)